# How to update row by id using case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, case

Is it possible to update by id other row values?

I try like this
But nothig..

```
UPDATE era 
SET id = CASE
    WHEN id = 3 THEN gender = 'Female'--or maybe it is possible to call insert command here? insert into era (gender) values 'female'?
    WHEN id = 4 THEN gender = 'Male'
END;
```

I would kike to have values changed in my table in the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the column `gender` then you should use it in `SET` instead of `id` like this:

```
UPDATE era 
SET gender = CASE id
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Female'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Male'
END
WHERE id IN (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware how big your update is but It is possible using the table in `from` clause join and then slight change to the `case` statement as,

```
update era u
   set gender = case 
                 when f.id = 3
                  then 'Female'
                 when f.id = 4
                  then 'Male'
                end
  from era f
 where u.id = f.id
```

Comment: @Anton Griduhsko, For your use case you can go for other options which are mentioned by other users but with `from clause  and join` you can use n other tables which might be required for updating different columns based on value from those other table columns.